# Copy selection into email recipient using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've wanted to try a Chrome Extension for a while, and one thing that always bugged me about Chrome is that clicking on an active `mailto:` link opens GMail (if it's your handler) in the same tab, navigating away from the page.

When you click on a `mailto:` link using the Gmail handler, it takes the linked email address and appends it to the Compose window:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&source=mailto&to=youremail@somesite.com
```

What I want to do is create an extension that gives me a context menu option to compose a new email. I've got the basics down (see below) but I cannot figure out how to get the recipients email address automatically included in the popup.

**manifest.json:**

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },

"description": "Creates a context menu option which copies the selected address into a new Gmail compose window.",

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "New Gmail Window",
"permissions": [ "tabs", "contextMenus" ],
"version": "0.1"
}
```

**background.js**

```
function getEmail(info, tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1&", // This is the URL I need to figure out.
        width: 640,
        height: 700,
        focused: true,
        type: "popup",
    })
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Send Email",
    contexts: ["selection"],
    targetUrlPatterns: ["mailto:* "],
    onclick: getEmail,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're 99% of the way there. This is the simple fix to get the email address in there:

```
url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1&to="+info.linkUrl.substr(7),
```

`info.linkUrl` grabs the whole "mailto:someone@domain.com", and the `.substr(7)` just cuts off the `"mailto:"` portion.

Additional Notes:

- Who wants to have to select (i.e., highlight) the email link? I recommend including links in the context (`contexts: ["selection", "link"]`).
- You have a space at the end of you `targetUrlPatterns` (`["mailto:* "`). I'm not sure why it isn't messing anything up on the selections I've tried. But it does mess things up when you add "link" to the contexts to be able to email with just a right-click.

Comment: Also, I hate to say it, but there are a few extensions that already do this. For example, [Send using Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-using-gmail-no-butto/ahldefgplekckalfcolhhnljbbgaiboc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) will open the composition url in a pop-up window if you choose the 'in a new window' option in the settings.

Comment: I did find that one, but I wanted to do this myself for a couple reasons. 1, to get some experience. 2, I tried that extension, and I couldn't get the "new window" option to work. 3, I want to be able to customize this to my own use, and I probably won't publish it. That'll let me mess around without screwing anyone else up. Thanks, though, for the help. I'll play with it later and see how it goes.

Comment: Just our of curiosity, would the "selection" context item pull the text selected into the email recipient? For example, someone has their email listed, but not as a link. If I highlight it, should it throw that into the to: field?

Comment: No, the array of options declared in the context setting only controls when chrome does/doesn't add your custom item to the context menu (all right clicks? Only when right clicking an image? Only when right clicking a highlight/selection?, etc). But once you select a menu option from the context menu, Chrome sends the same bundle of information to the javascript function that's registered as a handler - see [the developer documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData)

Comment: Realized I didn't answer your Q as directly as I should have. If the right click is on a link, the link's `href` will be returned as `info.linkUrl` (assuming you name the returned bundle "info"). If the right click is a selection, then the selected text will be returned as `info.selectionText`. If you wanted to handle emails that aren't in links, you could do something like 'if info.linkUrl=nothing but info.selectionText=something, to=selectionText'